# Get HTTP headers in asynchronous WebClient request

Tags: c#, http, asynchronous, webclient

I'm using `System.Net.WebClient` to perform some HTTP operations in asynchronous mode. The reason to use asynchronous operations is, above anything else, the fact that I get progress change indications - which is only available for async operations, as stated by [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.uploadprogresschanged.aspx).

So let's say I have my WebClient set up:

```
this.client = new WebClient();
this.client.UploadStringCompleted +=
    new UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(textUploadComplete);
```

and the delegate:

```
private void textUploadComplete(Object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error != null)
    {
        // trigger UI failure notification
        return;
    }

    // FIXME not checking for response code == 200 (OK)
    // trigger UI success notification
}
```

So you see, I'm assuming that if no exception is raised, the requests was always successful (which may not be the case, since the HTTP response status code can be != 2xx). From the documentation on [UploadFileAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144232.aspx) I can't tell if a non-200 response is processed as well.

I'm **really new** to C# and I can't seem to find a way to access the headers for that particular asynchronous request's response. Seems to me that each `WebClient` can only hold a response (or a set of headers) at any given time.

While I'm not going to be executing multiple parallel requests at the same time, I'd still like to know if there is a more elegant way of retrieving a particular request's response headers/status code, rather than having to get the "last-available" response from the `WebClient`.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you in .NET 4.5? If so try using the TaskAsync overloads ... you would still need to access the headers from WebClient class, but I wouldn't find this objectionable at all using the TAP workflow ... I agree it feels a little wrong to do it in an ordinary event handler. `await client.UploadStringTaskAsync(...); var headers = client.ResponseHeaders;`

Answer (score 1):

get headers from the sender object
i just added one line to your code above

```
  private void textUploadComplete(Object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            var headers = (sender as WebClient)?.ResponseHeaders; //HEADERS
            if (e.Error != null)
            {
                // trigger UI failure notification
                return;
            }

            // FIXME not checking for response code == 200 (OK)
            // trigger UI success notification
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you in .NET 4.5? If so try using the TaskAsync overloads ... you would still need to access the headers from WebClient instance, but I wouldn't find this objectionable at all using the TAP workflow ... I agree it feels a little wrong to do it in an ordinary event handler.

```
await client.UploadStringTaskAsync(...); 
var headers = client.ResponseHeaders;
```

Best of all you can do it all on the UI thread ... won't block ... so your 'trigger update UI' is really just 'Update UI'.